# Resource Booking Scenario

Tags: sql

Hi i have a scenario as follows-:

I have to book a resource on a particular date from  10.00 AM to 11 AM so have to check that particular resource is free on that date.

Note that the resource is booked for following hours.
09.00 AM to 10.AM &
11.00 AM to 12.PM

I have to query the table whether 10.00 AM to 11 AM  booking is available .If yes will return true.

Comment: Hi there. Post the actual RDBMS (SQL? Oracle? MySQL?), The definition of your tables and what you have tried so far and we will be able to help. Can you look at the problem you have posed so far and see any kind of logical expression that will give you what you need.

Comment: To sort this problem we need to see `table schema` atleast

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query would need to ensure that no other reservations overlap with the interval you're trying to book.

If your reservations are stored as inclusive-exclusive time periods in a table like this:

`CREATE TABLE reservations (
rsrc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
dtbegin DATETIME NOT NULL,
dtend DATETIME NOT NULL,
booking_event_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (rsrc_id, dtbegin, dtend)
)`

then the following search would need to return a count of zero to demonstrate that resource 1234 is currently available to be booked from 10am to 11am on February 1st:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservations 
WHERE rsrc_id = 1234 AND
(
    ( '2015-02-01 10:00:00' >= dtbegin AND '2015-02-01 10:00:00' < dtend )
    OR
    ( '2015-02-01 11:00:00' > dtbegin AND '2015-02-01 11:00:00' <= dtend )
    OR
    ( dtbegin >= '2015-02-01 10:00:00' AND dtend <= '2015-02-01 11:00:00' )
)`